# how to enable a entry by clicking a button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to activate many entries when button is clicked

please do not write class based code, modify this code only because i need to change the whole code for the project as i did my whole project without classes

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
x='disabled'
def rakhi():
   global x
   x='NORMAL'
root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
entry1=Entry(frame,state=x)
entry1.pack()
entry2=Entry(frame,state=x)
entry2.pack()
button1=Button(frame,text="press",command=rakhi)
button1.pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `configure` method of each widget:

```
def rakhi():
    entry1.configure(state="normal")
    entry2.configure(state="normal")
```